# Insert a large file ( 9MB) from a LWC into a Case

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, community, salesforce1-app, salesforce-id

I am trying to upload a file ( that has for example 4.9 MB) and my component throw an error, although everything is working fine with smaller files ( up to 3MB) !
I know I must update the logic in my apex class but I am a bit lost on how to start or what to do exactly

Any thoughts or ideas are welcome!

Here's my code :

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static String saveFile(ContentVersionItem contentVersionItem) {
        String base64Data = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(contentVersionItem.versionData, 'UTF-8');

        ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
        cv.Title = contentVersionItem.title;
        cv.PathOnClient = contentVersionItem.pathOnClient;
        cv.FirstPublishLocationId = contentVersionItem.firstPublishLocationId;
        cv.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Data);
        // cv.VersionData = Blob.valueOf(base64Data);
        cv.IsMajorVersion = contentVersionItem.isMajorVersion;

        insert cv;

        return JSON.serialize(cv);
    }

    public class ContentVersionItem {
        
        public ContentVersionItem(){}
        @AuraEnabled
        public String title { get; set; }

        @AuraEnabled
        public String pathOnClient { get; set; }

        @AuraEnabled
        public String firstPublishLocationId { get; set; }

        @AuraEnabled
        public String versionData { get; set; }

        @AuraEnabled
        public Boolean isMajorVersion { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't upload files that large in Apex. Use [lightning-file-upload](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-file-upload) to upload files up to 2GB in size.

Comment: but can I customize the css of the lightning-file-upload ? cause i want to use this functionality inside a form in a community page